# Grey pixels added when picture retrieved

Tags: android, bitmap, firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase to store pictures for my app. I'm using a fragment which holds custom views to hold them within my app, with the xml for the imageview:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_imageView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="Product Picture"/>
```

To actually populate the imagviews in my custom views I retrieve the bytes from Firebase and use a bitmapfactory to assemble the image, store it in memory, and set its value to my imageview:

```
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(item.getImageUrl());

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    httpsReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
        }
    });
}
```

But when I compile my code I get:
[image]

I want the pictures to all be the same height and wrap content on width and obviously not have those grey pixels added. Any suggestions are appreciated thank you in advance.

EDIT

Issue resolved itself somehow. Ran the application again this afternoon and bars disappeared. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to play with that value - `final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;` ? Try to increase it - any changes?

Comment: That's just a value to make sure there is sufficient memory to store the image. But just for fun I did try changing it to several values to no avail.

Comment: Try to change android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Didn't do anything to it. I messed around with those values a little more as well and if it gets to a low enough number the image doesn't show up at all. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: If you view the image in the Firebase Storage console, does it also show the gray bar? if so, you most likely aborted uploading of the image before it was finished.

Comment: It doesn't have the gray bars but it is badly proportioned. I didn't do anything during the upload process though.